# ESP32 Welcome screen transition to another screen?

Tags: esp32, arduino-esp32

I'm making a simple car gauge, I want to add a little personal touch nothing special.
Setup: ESP32 and ST7735S with no SD card.

At the beginning I want to add a boot screen ( picture- I use flash memory for this because I have no SD card tftIcons.ino)
After like 5s I want to transition from picture to my gauges ( simple print code for now) But I don't know how to stich these two together to get what I want.

The code for Welcome screen/ Boot is:

```
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>    // Core graphics library
#include <Adafruit_ST7735.h> // Hardware-specific library

#include "bitmaps.h"
#include "bitmapsLarge.h"

// For the breakout, you can use any 2 or 3 pins
// These pins will also work for the 1.8" TFT shield
#define TFT_CS     5
#define TFT_RST    4  // you can also connect this to the Arduino reset
                      // in which case, set this #define pin to 0!
#define TFT_DC     2

Adafruit_ST7735 tft = Adafruit_ST7735(TFT_CS,  TFT_DC, TFT_RST);

void setup() {
  tft.initR(INITR_BLACKTAB);
  tft.setRotation(0);
  tft.fillScreen(ST7735_BLACK);


//Case 2: Multi Colored Images/Icons
  int h = 160,w = 128, row, col, buffidx=0;
  for (row=0; row<h; row++) { // For each scanline...
    for (col=0; col<w; col++) { // For each pixel...
      //To read from Flash Memory, pgm_read_XXX is required.
      //Since image is stored as uint16_t, pgm_read_word is used as it uses 16bit address
      tft.drawPixel(col, row, pgm_read_word(evive_in_hand + buffidx));
      buffidx++;
    } // end pixel
  }
}

void loop() {
}
```

The code for the gauges is:

```
    #include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>    // Core graphics library
#include <Adafruit_ST7735.h> // Hardware-specific library

#define TFT_CS        5
#define TFT_RST        4 // Or set to -1 and connect to Arduino RESET pin
#define TFT_DC         2

Adafruit_ST7735 tft = Adafruit_ST7735(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST);

float p = 3.1415926;

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print(F("Hello! ST77xx TFT Test"));

  // Use this initializer if using a 1.8" TFT screen:
  tft.initR(INITR_BLACKTAB);      // Init ST7735S chip, black tab
  tft.setRotation(1); // set display orientation 
}

void loop() {
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  print_text(20,5,"1.54",5,ST77XX_GREEN);
  print_text(70,50,"BAR",2,ST77XX_GREEN);
  print_text(5,90,"Temp motora: 81'C",1,ST77XX_WHITE);
  print_text(5,100,"Temp usisa: 30'C",1,ST77XX_BLUE);
  print_text(146,116,"AM",1,ST77XX_WHITE);
  

  delay(5000);
  
  
}

void print_text(byte x_pos, byte y_pos, char *text, byte text_size, uint16_t color) {
  tft.setCursor(x_pos, y_pos);
  tft.setTextSize(text_size);
  tft.setTextColor(color);
  tft.setTextWrap(true);
  tft.print(text);
}
```

Can someone tell me how can I make when I power on ESP32 to show Welcome screen/ boot screen for 5s, then automatically transition to Gauges screen ?

EDIT: When I join these two

```
    #include <Adafruit_GFX.h>    // Core graphics library
#include <Adafruit_ST7735.h> // Hardware-specific library
#include <SPI.h>


#include "bitmaps.h"
#include "bitmapsLarge.h"

// For the breakout, you can use any 2 or 3 pins
// These pins will also work for the 1.8" TFT shield
#define TFT_CS     5
#define TFT_RST    4  // you can also connect this to the Arduino reset
                      // in which case, set this #define pin to 0!
#define TFT_DC     2

Adafruit_ST7735 tft = Adafruit_ST7735(TFT_CS,  TFT_DC, TFT_RST);

void setup() {
  tft.initR(INITR_BLACKTAB);
  tft.setRotation(0);
  tft.fillScreen(ST7735_BLACK);


//Case 2: Multi Colored Images/Icons
  int h = 160,w = 128, row, col, buffidx=0;
  for (row=0; row<h; row++) { // For each scanline...
    for (col=0; col<w; col++) { // For each pixel...
      //To read from Flash Memory, pgm_read_XXX is required.
      //Since image is stored as uint16_t, pgm_read_word is used as it uses 16bit address
      tft.drawPixel(col, row, pgm_read_word(evive_in_hand + buffidx));
      buffidx++;
    } // end pixel
  }
  delay(5000);  // Delay 5s, then run the code down?
}

     // Timer 


float p = 3.1415926;


  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print(F("Hello! ST77xx TFT Test"));

  // Use this initializer if using a 1.8" TFT screen:
  tft.initR(INITR_BLACKTAB);      // Init ST7735S chip, black tab
  tft.setRotation(1); // set display orientation 


void loop() {
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  print_text(20,5,"1.54",5,ST77XX_GREEN);
  print_text(70,50,"BAR",2,ST77XX_GREEN);
  print_text(5,90,"Temp motora: 81'C",1,ST77XX_WHITE);
  print_text(5,100,"Temp usisa: 30'C",1,ST77XX_BLUE);
  print_text(146,116,"AM",1,ST77XX_WHITE);
  

  delay(5000);
  
  
}

void print_text(byte x_pos, byte y_pos, char *text, byte text_size, uint16_t color) {
  tft.setCursor(x_pos, y_pos);
  tft.setTextSize(text_size);
  tft.setTextColor(color);
  tft.setTextWrap(true);
  tft.print(text);
}
```

I get exit status 1
'Serial' does not name a type

Comment: What do you mean by "transition"? Is there specific visual effect you have in mind? Otherwise is there a problem with just clearing the screen and then displaying the screen you want?

Comment: No special effect. I just want the first [code1] to show for 5s (image), and then move to other [code2] ( print messages) no time limit. I think what i need id code1 delay 5s and then code 2 shows up. But i don't know how to implement it in these two codes I tried but i get "{" errors

Comment: If I were you I'd edit the question to ask about the specific errors you're getting; Stack Overflow works a lot better with that kind of question than with broader questions like the one you asked.

Comment: Thanks but that would be even worse. This code works individually when i upload it to my ESP32. I just want to join the first [code1] and [code2] into one. [Code1] should last 5s. that's all.

Comment: You said "I tried but i get "{" errors". Asking about that is more likely to get you help.

Comment: I've added what I thing might work, but i get exit status 1
'Serial' does not name a type

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>    // Core graphics library
#include <Adafruit_ST7735.h> // Hardware-specific library
#include "bitmaps.h"
#include "bitmapsLarge.h"

#define TFT_CS        5
#define TFT_RST        4 // Or set to -1 and connect to Arduino RESET pin
#define TFT_DC         2

Adafruit_ST7735 tft = Adafruit_ST7735(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST);

float p = 3.1415926;

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print(F("Hello! ST77xx TFT Test"));
 tft.initR(INITR_BLACKTAB);
  tft.setRotation(0);
  tft.fillScreen(ST7735_BLACK);


//Case 2: Multi Colored Images/Icons
  int h = 160,w = 128, row, col, buffidx=0;
  for (row=0; row<h; row++) { // For each scanline...
    for (col=0; col<w; col++) { // For each pixel...
      //To read from Flash Memory, pgm_read_XXX is required.
      //Since image is stored as uint16_t, pgm_read_word is used as it uses 16bit address
      tft.drawPixel(col, row, pgm_read_word(evive_in_hand + buffidx));
      buffidx++;
    } // end pixel
  }
  delay(5000);
  // Use this initializer if using a 1.8" TFT screen:
  tft.initR(INITR_BLACKTAB);      // Init ST7735S chip, black tab
  tft.setRotation(1); // set display orientation 
}

void loop() {
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  print_text(20,5,"1.54",5,ST77XX_GREEN);
  print_text(70,50,"BAR",2,ST77XX_GREEN);
  print_text(5,90,"Temp motora: 81'C",1,ST77XX_WHITE);
  print_text(5,100,"Temp usisa: 30'C",1,ST77XX_BLUE);
  print_text(146,116,"AM",1,ST77XX_WHITE);
  

  delay(5000);
  
  
}

void print_text(byte x_pos, byte y_pos, char *text, byte text_size, uint16_t color) {
  tft.setCursor(x_pos, y_pos);
  tft.setTextSize(text_size);
  tft.setTextColor(color);
  tft.setTextWrap(true);
  tft.print(text);
}
```

I fount out how. You can only have one void setup and void loop. You cant c/p stich two together